# Keeping track of multiple clients on grpc server

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I am trying to create a `grpc` python server that can keep track of all clients connected.

I am referencing a talk/demo that Ray Tsang did where he kept a collection of `StreamObservers` and just iterated through them to send to all the clients. Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/DU-q5kOf2Rc?t=38m35s) of that for reference.

Now my question is how do you get a `StreamObserver` in python? I only see `self`, `request` and `context` as being available to me in the definition.

This is my first python project so there might be something obvious I am missing here.

Here is my proto, its basically the sample proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package hellostreamingworld;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
  // Sends another greeting
  rpc SayHelloAgain (HelloRequest) returns (stream HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like Python syntax. You probably should start there.

Comment: Just to understant your goal... grpc is a framework, that can be used in python, on theyr official website you can follow the python starter guide that explain how to install/interact (look here https://grpc.io/docs/ under "python"), have you already do that?

Comment: @ChenA. I didn't say that was python syntax I said that was my `proto` file for the `grpc` framework. The question is how do you keep track of multiple clients with python `grpc`

Comment: @Legion I have no problem installing/using grpc I am just trying to understand how to keep track of multiple clients as in the java example in the video. I don't see any `StreamObserver` or know how to get access to one in python

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand you need to create a class ClientInterceptor that extends grpc.UnaryUnaryClientInterceptor(https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html?highlight=unaryunaryclientinterceptor#grpc.UnaryUnaryClientInterceptor) 
and then assign it with the intercept_channel method in this way

```
self.channel = grpc.insecure_channel(address, options)

self.channel = grpc.intercept_channel(
     self.channel,
     ClientInterceptor()
)
```

You can use the intercept_unary_unary method for receive infos about the various clients.

If you want to have infos server side extends the ServerInterceptor(https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html?highlight=serverinterceptor#grpc.ServerInterceptor) and assign it on the server init

```
self.server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1000),
                          options=(('grpc.max_send_message_length', 1000 * 1024 * 1024,),
                                   ('grpc.max_receive_message_length', 1000 * 1024 * 1024,),
                                  ),
                          interceptors=(MyServerInterceptor())
                         )
```

And the use the intercept_service method for receive infos.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is a bidirectional stream service. That is both the client and server are continuously sending data over. In this case gRPC + python will keep track of your client!
Check out [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/7c0764918b9f33cab507ff483b4be849b0203ec4/examples/python/route_guide/route_guide_server.py#L107) example code and corresponding [explanation](https://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python/).